# Is there any way to mock a function in clojure?

Tags: testing, clojure

Is there any way to mock a function in clojure. For example I have this function: `(defn a [x] (utils/count x))` I need to write a test, but I do not know how to mock the utils/count (for example). what if I have several functions inside the same function and I need to test it? `(defn a [x] (utils/count x) (utils/count2 x) (test/other x))`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `with-redefs` e.g.

```
(deftest t
  (with-redefs [utils/count (fn [x] 2)
                utils/count2 (fn [x] 3)
                test/other (fn [x y] :result)]
    (let [result (a 2)])))
```

Answer (score 2):

See also https://ask.clojure.org/index.php/9077/how-do-you-mock-in-clojure which suggests organizing your code so you don't need mocks, where possible.

Comment: That site is bizarre. Who decided that Cognitect should host a reskin of Stack Overflow and seed it with Jira tickets as if they were question?

Comment: @amalloy read https://ask.clojure.org/index.php/about which explains what it is and why it exists; also see some of the questions in https://ask.clojure.org/index.php/meta which talk about the tech behind it (the open source Question2Answer app)